# getting input value after it has been formatted to currency with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form. On this form I when I add line items I save the input value then prepend it to the form. This part works. Keep in mind the form is not being submitted I am just adding to the dom dynamically

In the part of the form I save there is a price input. I am using jquerypriceformat plugin to format the price into price format. For example 111 becomes $1.11. If I do not use the plugin it works. The plugin does work as intended. I think my problem is that after I type the value is being changed and I need to retain that value somehow.

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ks2z5mdo/7/

I think the fiddle will better show what the problem is. Basically when you type a description type a quantity and price, the price gets formatted then hit the add button all the data is saved except the price.

How can I solve this?

So first is the form

```
<div class="form-row">
    <strong>Line Items:</strong>
    <br>
    <div class="line-items">
        <div class="line-item">
            <div class="line-item-box description">
                <label>Description:</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
            </div><!--
         --><div class="line-item-box quantity">
                <label>Quantity:</label>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
            </div><!--
         --><div class="line-item-box price">
                <label>Price:</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
            </div>
            <button class="btn add-item">Add Item</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Then is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#price').priceFormat();
    $('.add-item').click(function() {
        if ($('description, #quantity, #price').filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).length > 0) {
            var description = $('#description').val();
            var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
            var price = $('#price').val();
            $('.line-items').prepend('<div class="line-item"><div class="line-item-box description">' + description + '</div><div class="line-item-box quantity">' + quantity + '</div><div class="line-item-box price">' + price*quantity + '</div><button class="btn remove-btn">Remove</button></div>');
             return false;
         } else {
             alert('Line item empty');
         }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
        $('.line-item').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var price = $('#price').val();` adds a `$` and a space in front of the actual value that you are trying to get. Therefore, one solution is to get the substring of this value to remove the $:

```
var price = $('#price').val().substring(2);
```

This will leave the value as a number rather than the string it was originally made to be. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks2z5mdo/10/) that works.

Comment: ah but then the value that gets saved is not the full price with cents and dollar sign. Is there a way to keep the currency as it is?

Comment: I think you will have to add on the dollar sign again afterwards in the div where you want the currency to show up, as I don't think there is a way to multiply the number when there is the dollar sign in fron tof it.

Comment: I've updated it to show the dollar sign at the end. You just have to add the "$" before the price*quantity in the prepend.

Comment: Thank you I better understand the problem now and will be able to solve.